# How to integrate multiple Vue Js components into a legacy system?

Tags: javascript, java, vue.js, vuejs2, legacy

I have a legacy multipage system written in Java that has a dashboard as a Vue project. The dashboard component is called on App.vue so when building, the page that needs the dashboard calls the build files. However, now I need to use Vue on another different page, and if I just put the same id as the App, I'll get the dashboard too, which I don't want to.

I've searched a lot and its confusing, I saw that I have to deal with webpack config, entries, or make multiple vue instances/apps.

What I'm doing right now is creating new vue() on main.js to export my new component with its own id so I can use it on the other page I want. So on main.js I have two new vue for now.

On the webpack approach, what I think it's confusing is, if I make bundles for each component, how can I call that on a div, for example, like the way ids work with instances?

Multiple vue instances seems easier, is it a bad practice? What is the best approach here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option on this is exploring custom elements, already supported by Vue 2 (Vue 3 is currently in progress).

Custom Elements aka webcomponents enables the possibility to integrate components inside any html page.

Check the following documentation: [vue official doc for webcomponents](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#web-component) and also official webcomponents documentation [official webcomponents documentation](https://www.webcomponents.org/introduction)

Comment: Oh, that's simpler than what I saw using webpack config! It works, but since I'm using Vuetify, Vuetify doesnt load, do you have any tips for that? I'm searching for a solution and only saw that I had to import all components one by one, so I wonder if I can do it in any other way

Comment: Vuetify doesn't load when you build as webcomponent? It depends on the use case I would say. I already built a vue 2 application with tailwind inside and I had no problems. Maybe there is something about the way you installed vuetify on your package.json. and maybe that is messing up your Vuetify loading.

Comment: It loads only on one part, I guess it has to do with my config indeed, I tried with a lib vue-custom-components and it was easier but still no luck with vuetify... But thanks for the help, I guess vue web components are just new instances after all